# hdaudioCOD3 unable to bind the codec

Tags: 19.04, ubuntu-drivers

After boot grub ubuntu 19.04, it freeze at line: [77.212966] hdaudio hdaudioCOD3: unable to bind the codec
Can anyone help to fix this?

======================

Well,, i fix it by entering the recovery mode, and repair all the broken packages.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from livecd (same version of your distro) and mount (get your `sdaX` with `sudo fdisk -l`) then

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo mount --bind /etc /mnt/etc
sudo chroot /mnt
```

don't forget to comment the line that starts with `deb cdrom:` under `/etc/apt/sources.list` then

1. Back up the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file
2. Open original file and clean **only the content** after **Depends:** (all lines) use a editor like vscode
3. Then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

This will force all packages upgrade they dependencies and fixed `hdaudio hdaudioCOD3: unable to bind the codec`